# Issue with similar questions list when asking a question

Tags: bug, design

When asking a new question on the site, a list of similar questions is displayed on the right. When scrolling down, this list is fixed and goes above the footer text as in the screenshot below (using Google Chrome v.31):

[image: Similar questions list]

By the way, the same issue is also present here on meta:

[image: Similar questions on meta.ux]

Comment: This is an issue stackexchange site-wide, not just here. It's been brought up quite a bit on the main meta.Stackoverflow site - see the canonical post here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/136849/right-hand-sidebar-covers-the-footer-on-the-ask-question-page-and-markdown-hel?lq=1 but also lots of duplicates in the 'Linked' questions section on the right-hand column of that post. Unfortunately it doesn't look like anything has / will be done about this any time soon.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't think about having a look on the main meta.stackoverflow... Anyway, thank you for the feedback!